# Access to value of the variable in if statement

Tags: swift, if-statement

I need to access the value of a variable in a if statement, this is my code:

```
var codeError : Int?

@IBAction func mySwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
     if sender.isOn {
        codeError = 1
     } else {
        codeError = 2
     }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if codeError == 1 {
       front()
    } else if codeError == 2 {
       back()
    }

}
```

My two functions, this is my front() function:

```
    func front() {

    let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInDualCamera, AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInTelephotoCamera,AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: AVCaptureDevicePosition.unspecified)

    for device in (deviceDiscoverySession?.devices)! {


        if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.front {

            do {

                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
                if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {

                    captureSession.addInput(input)

                    if captureSession.canAddOutput(photoOutput) {

                        captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput)
                        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                        previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                        previewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
                        cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)


                    }

                }

            } catch {

                print("Error")

            }

        }

    }

    captureSession.startRunning()
    print("")

}
```

And back() function:

```
    func back() {

    let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInDualCamera, AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInTelephotoCamera,AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: AVCaptureDevicePosition.unspecified)

    for device in (deviceDiscoverySession?.devices)! {


        if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.back {

            do {

                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
                if cS.canAddInput(input) {

                    cS.addInput(input)

                    if cS.canAddOutput(photoOutput) {

                        cS.addOutput(photoOutput)
                        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: cS)
                        previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                        previewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
                        cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)


                    }

                }

            } catch {

                print("Error")

            }

        }

    }

    cS.startRunning()
    print("")

}
```

The problem is when I run the app. I get a nil value of the codeError when I should get 1 o 2.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What exactly is your issue?

Comment: Just put your code into the block statement:
`@IBAction func mySwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
     if sender.isOn {
        // Write code here
        codeError = 1
     } else {
         // Write code here
        codeError = 2
     }
}`

Comment: But I need to print 1 or 2 outside of the if statement

Comment: `codeError = sender.isOn ? 1 : 2` and to print an optional type `print(codeError ?? "nil")`

Answer (score 0):

it is working like you original code. but you print it inside `viewWillAppear`. but at this time it is not initialized from you uiswitch.

one solution: give it default value:

```
var codeError: Int = 1
```

or shorter

```
var codeError = 1
```

**Note:**

> viewWillAppear(_:)
>
> Notifies the view controller that its view is about to be added to a view hierarchy.

see https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear

but it is called on the view where your UISwitch is on. for your main goal (hidden in comments on the other answer) it is the wrong place to print out the variable

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're accessing a variable set by user when interacting with the view on `viewWillAppear`. I suggest spending some time and studying UIViewController life cycles.

But if you just want to print error codes on switch changing values, this should do it.

```
var codeError : Int?

@IBAction func mySwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
     if sender.isOn {
        codeError = 1
     } else {
        codeError = 2
     }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    // will print nothing since errorCode is not set
    printCodeError()
}

func printCodeError() {
  if let codeError = self.codeError {
    print("\(codeError)")
  }
}
```

Comment: codeError is an example, if codeError prints 1 add a function to open the front camera and if codeError prints 2, I open the back camera. That's the reason for use viewWillAppear

Comment: then change `print("1")` to `openFrontCamera()` and `print(2)` to `openBackCamera()` and write these functions to do just that.

Comment: you should add your main goal to your question. then we can help you better